# A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I am seeing this error

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts
```

when I did the below code. I am retrieving from Dynamo by Global secondary Index and I am getting the items from Dynamo perfectly fine. I am returning Employee as a response but Im getting this error. Please help below is my code.

```
async getByIndex(index: string): Promise<Employee> {
const params = {
  TableName: table-name,
  IndexName: indexName,
  KeyConditionExpression: expression,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    values
  },
};
const response = await this.dynamoDocumentClient.query(params).promise();

if (!response?.Items) {
  throw new NotFoundException('id');
}

response.Items.forEach((item) => {
  return item as Employee;
});
}
```

Comment: Your `getByIndex` function is not returning anything. You have a `return` statement in an _inner function_ inside the `forEach`, which has no bearing on the outer function. I'm curious what that `forEach` is supposed to be doing. Seems like you could just have `return response.Items;`

Comment: @JLRishe I am returning Promise<Employee>. I want the forEach to return the first item or any item.

Comment: Then just `return response.Items[0]`. There's no need to loop through it.